# CSS - Image Full Screen, but will maintain aspect ratio

Tags: html, css, aspect-ratio

How do I get an image to fill the full screen (note there is stuff below it - think of it as a header in a page that fills the whole screen) but maintains its aspect ratio, either overspilling on the width or oversplilling on the height.

I thought it would be:

```
<img class="w3-image" src="./images/img1.jpg" style="min-width:100vw; max-height:100vh; background-position: center; background-repeat: no-repeat;" />
```

But that does not work. The aspect ratio fails.

Comment: Have you tried using `background-size: cover;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert it as a background to an element instead, with `background-size: cover;` and the element with `height: 100vh`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you may use

```
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
min-height: 100vh;
min-width: 100vh;
```

http://codepen.io/powaznypowazny/pen/apeVXg

Hope it helps :)